# how replace \"*\ with space in string in c#

Tags: c#, string, replace, character

i have string like this = `"Code\"*\"Code2"`.
the string should be = `"Code" "Code2"`.
how can I remove characters between code and code2 and replace it with space?

Comment: read about `string.Replace`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to solve this problem if you know the exact problem statement.

```
string temp = "Code\"*\\Code2";
string newStr = temp.Replace("\"*\\", "");
```

You can also use `Remove` method which takes the start index and length as the parameter.

We can try removing the string between two given strings from a string also by using the `LastIndexOf` and `IndexOf` methods for the given words.

**Update** as per the OP clarification the expected output should be

> "Code" "Code2"

**.Net Core 3.1 Solution:**

```
string temp = "Code\"*\\Code2";
string[] arr = temp.Split("\"*\\");
var abc = arr.Select(x => (char)34 + x + (char)34);
string newStr = string.Join(' ', abc);
```

**.Net Framework 4.8 Solution:**

```
string temp = "Code\"*\\Code2";
string[] arr = temp.Split(new string[] { "\"*\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var abc = arr.Select(x => (char)34 + x + (char)34);
string newStr = string.Join(" ", abc);
```

**Note:** The ASCII value for a double quote is `34`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated my question. please read it again. my string is "Code\"*\"Code2"  and my desire string is = "Code" "Code2"

Comment: What result you want to be printed.

Comment: @hosseinzakizadeh then please modify your question. It is confusing

Comment: Ar you using winforms or uwp or wpf or console which framework or .net core?

Comment: i using console

Comment: What results to want to be printed your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: the result should be = "Code" "Code2"

Comment: I got an error in Split => cannot convert from string to char

Comment: @hosseinzakizadeh are you sing the code as it? Because I have tested and verified it in .net core 3.1. It's working as expected

Comment: I think your project is targeting to .net framework, I have added a solution for .net framework also. please check @hosseinzakizadeh

Comment: @hosseinzakizadeh have you solved the issue? You should respond if someone is spending time to help you. It’s basic courtesy

Answer (score 0):

Since `\` is also used to escape a quotation mark, your question it not quite clear. It could be either

```
string s = "Code\"*\"Code2";
string t = s.Replace("\"*\"", " ");
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

OR

```
string s = "\"Code\"\\*\\\"Code2\"";
string t = s.Replace("\\*\\", " ");
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

This will output `"Code" "Code2"`.

OR

```
string t = s.Replace("*", " ");
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

This will output `Code" "Code2`.

OR

```
string s = "\"Code\"*\"Code2\"";
string t = s.Replace("*", " ");
Console.WriteLine(t);
```

This will output `"Code" "Code2"`.

To make it more clear, please provide a code snippet such as the one here in the answer.

Comment: its remove " between Code and Code2. I need this: "Code" "Code2"

Comment: `string.Replace()` is totally the way to go. Again, from your question it is not 100% clear what your string right now looks like and how it should look, unless you provide a code snippet. See my updated answer, it should be more clear now.